# Fetching Sorted Array based on NSDate from Core Data Entity in iOS9 using Objective C

Tags: core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am using core data for storing alarm details (AlarmDate is stored as Date type), while fetching all alarms i have used NSSortDescripotor as

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Alarm"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"AlarmDate"
                                                               ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSArray *arrayForAllAlarms = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

for above it is returning the alarms in sorted order, **but i need it should also consider the AM and PM while sorting**

> Example:
>
> if alarms date are added like:
>   11.00 pm,
>   01.30 am and
>   10.00 pm
>
> it should return:
>   01.30 am
>   10.00 pm and
>   11.00 pm

Thank you!

Comment: If it is Date type already, this should be taken care automatically. Can you confirm? Is it String instead?

Comment: yeah, it of type Date only.

Comment: @Shripada is right, this should just work. Maybe if you add some detail about how you're creating the `AlarmDate` values it would help.

Comment: @TomHarrington: Thank for your reply, i am adding alarm date from date picker with format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"

Comment: how can i do this by manually sorting, instead doing this in fetch request?

Answer (score 0):

Find Solution, Written custom sorting for existing fetched array as following:

```
NSArray *arrayForAllAlarmsSorted = [arrayForAllAlarms sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                                        ^(Alarm *alarmObject1, Alarm *alarmObject2) {

                                            NSDate *dateForAlarm1 = [NSDate date:alarmObject1.alarmDateTime withFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
                                            NSDate *dateForAlarm2 = [NSDate date:alarmObject2.alarmDateTime withFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

                                            return [dateForAlarm1 compare:dateForAlarm2];
                                        }];
```

And the NSDate Category function written as:

```
+(NSDate *)date:(NSDate *)date withFormat:(NSString *)format {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format;

    NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];

    return newDate;
}
```